# const struct declaration

Tags: c, struct, constants, declaration

Can someone tell me the difference between these two versions of a declaration of a structure?

```
struct S
{
  uint8_t a;
};
```

and

```
const struct S
{
  uint8_t a;
}
```

Followed by:

```
void main(void)
{
  struct S s = {1};
  s.a++;
}
```

Hint, i've tried both versions for S in Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express so I know that both compile with errors.

Is the "const struct" doing nothing at all? "const struct S s = {1};" certainly does, but that's not the issue at the moment.

Regards
Rich

```
/********************************************/
```

I've just worked out what

```
const struct <typename> <{type}> <variable instances a, b, .., z>;
```

is doing:

When const is present before the "struct", all variable instances are const, as though they'd be defined with:

```
const struct <typename> a, b, z;
```

So it does do something, but not when there's no instance definitions in-line with the struct declaration.

Rich

Comment: There's a missing semi-colon at the end of the second one, which means you've specified two different types in the place where the return type of `main` belongs. Neither of those types is what it should be -- `int`. I can't remember whether or not you're allowed to define a type in a function definition (and anyway it's not entirely clear to what language you're compiling this code as), that could be an additional error.

Comment: Other than void main(), what other problems are there @KerrekSB

Comment: Sorry about the C++, I deleted my comment. @Rich: You're missing a semicolon in the second snippet, and `void main(void)` is not allowed.

Comment: Is there any chance you could show us the code you are actually working with. The missing semi-colon makes me think there may be other issues.

Comment: The lack of a semi-colon is cus i typed it in free-hand. That isn't the issue here.
@SteveJessop its PHP (sarc)

Comment: I'm not talking rubbish when I said I compiled void main(void) in VC++ 2010. Go try it before telling me a 2nd time that it doesnt work.

Comment: @Rich: I mean it's not entirely clear whether you're really compiling it as C or C++. Given the various errors in your question, the C tag alone doesn't entirely fill me with confidence. Kerrek didn't say it doesn't work, he said it isn't allowed. He meant in the language, and it's true whether it's C or C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With:

```
const struct S
{
  uint8_t a;
};
```

The `const` qualifier there is nonsense, and may even cause a compilation error with some C compilers. `gcc` issues a warning.

The intent appears to be to declare the data type `struct S`. In this case, the proper syntax is:

```
struct S
{
  uint8_t a;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, my VC didnt issue a warning, nor did my Motorola HS12 compiler about this. It arose from working on some embedded code. I thought i'd dip back to VC and check my findings over const struct declaration. I'll give that a go in gcc!

Answer (score 8):

A declaration of structure just defines the data type.

`const` qualifier appies to a variable not a data type. So adding const preceeding a struct declaration should be redundant at the most.

Comment: I think this is +1 because of the distinction between "types" and "qualifiers", which is important here.

Answer (score 2):

```
const struct S
{
  uint8_t a;
};
```

is not a valid construct.

This

```
const struct S
{
  uint8_t a;
} x;
```

could possibly be valid as you're declaring a variable `x` that is now `const`, meaning it cannot change.

Comment: The semi-colon on the end of the struct was an accident. I'm defining my s in main() not inline with the struct declaration.

Comment: In fact, i've just tried

const struct S
    {
      uint8_t a;
    };

in VC and it's compiled without giving any variable instance names. So maybe we all need to check our songbooks before posting "X is wrong" in someone's post.

Answer (score 2):

The `const` qualifier applies to variables or members.
To instantiate a `const` variable, just specify `const` during instantiation.

What `const` does, is:

- during compilation, verify that only reads are performed on the const variables
- if the `const` variable is created with a value which can be resolved during compilation, put the variable in the program memory

When `const` is applied to members, like in:

```
struct T {
    int const i;
    int j;
};
```

You can only (legally) assign the value `i` during the creation of the structure.
You may be able to modify a `const` value (if the program memory sits in RAM and not ROM) by casting it to a non-const type (*const-cast*) but this is something you shouldn't do.

The typical usage of const-cast is when you use a library which does not specify the constness in function declarations, and your code does. At this point if you want to use it you have to trust it and cast parameters before calling its functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is nonsense to use `const` keyword before `struct`.

If you are using `gcc` compiler, it shows you the following warning:

> warning: useless type qualifier in empty declaration [enabled by default]

Answer (score 1):

This is the only use I can think of:

```
const struct S {
        int a;
        int b;
} s;
```

This declares a struct and immediately creates an instance for it named `s` and at this point, `a` and `b` in `s` are initialized to 0 (please note that at this point s is a global variable in the translation unit which it has been declared in and can be externally linked to).

```
printf("a = %d\t b = %d\n", s.a, s.b); // a = 0     b = 0
```

If you try to set members of `s`, you will fail:

```
s.a = 1; //error: assignment of member ‘a’ in read-only object
```

So, `s` is not really useful here...unless you do something like:

```
const struct S {
        int a;
        int b;
} s =  { 1, 2 };
```

Now let's create another instance of the same struct (declaration is still same as above):

```
    struct S other;
    other.a = 1;
    other.b = 2;

    printf("a = %d\t b = %d\n", other.a, other.b); // a = 1     b = 2
```

The compiler will not complain anymore as `other` is not const! only `s` is const!

Now, what that `const` do, you may ask? let's try to change s:

```
s = other; // error: assignment of read-only variable ‘s’
```

That is all to it. If you did not need the compiler to allocate storage for `s` at the point of declaration and still needed an instance of `s` to be const you would just add `const` at the point of instantiating `struct S` (note the capital S!!)

**Bonus 1**

```
const struct S {
        int a;
        int b;
};
```

note that there is no small `s` anymore. At this point, GCC will **warn** you that `const` qualifier does not do anything!!!!

**Bonus 2**

If you want every instance of the struct to be const, that is its members can only be initialized at the point of definition you can do like (using typedef):

```
typedef const struct S {
        int a;
        int b;
} s;

// The wrong way
s thisIsAnS;
thisIsAnS.a = 1; //error: assignment of member ‘a’ in read-only object 

// The correct way
s thisIsAnS = { 1 , 2 }; //compiles fine, but you can not change a or b anymore
```

**Conclusion**

To me, this is just syntactic sugar and only adds unnecessary complexity to the code. But who am I to judge...

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
const var;
```

then it allocate the some memory space for it but

```
struct var;
```

it was just an declaration compiler does not allocate any space for it.
so it shows the error and in const struct you didn't declare any varible see the code so it shows error.